# Pass any Options / Params to BigQuery via pydatalab

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I want to pass some more options than just `QueryParameters` (this is already possible) to a bigquery job I am executing with pydatalab through a [Query Object Instance](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/datalab.bigquery.html#datalab.bigquery.Query).

You can find available options in the docs for the API: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs

Maybe someone of you is more into that topic and can tell me how, for example, pass the `defaultDataset`.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not implemented in the library and there is no easy workaround. Have you considered filing a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/issues)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pydatalab, then you should take a look at the Python module called [google.datalab.bigquery](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/datalab.bigquery.html). This module allows you, amongs other things, to [initializes an instance of a Query object](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/datalab.bigquery.html#datalab.bigquery.Query) with different parameters (e.g.: sql query, context, sources, etc...).

You also have a class for the [DatasetName](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/datalab.bigquery.html#datalab.bigquery.DatasetName).

Not exactly sure why you need to set the default dataset. What you can do is something like:

```
my_obj = bq.DatasetName('myProjectId', 'myDatasetId')
```

and then you can get the datasetId: `my_obj.dataset_id`.

For instance:

```
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
my_obj = bq.DatasetName('projectid', 'datasetid')
query = bq.Query("SELECT * FROM " + "`" + my_obj.dataset_id + ".table`" + " LIMIT 1000")

output_options = bq.QueryOutput.table(use_cache=False)
result = query.execute(output_options=output_options).result()
result
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using it. I was not able to pass other options, especially not the defaultDatasetId

Comment: Understand Nico. You don't have the same options than using the API. I'll edit my answer to provide more details.

Comment: I know that I per default don't have the same options. But maybe somebody is aware of how to do that without requesting the API manually or easily patch that method

Comment: Thanks for editing. I do **not** want to manually format the query. I want to use some bypass options like defaultDatasetId (this is an example, not the question, one use case of passing defaultDataset would be to write queries for a production/staging system and execute them automatically on the right one, but keep them copy-pastable to the web ui).